# Understanding of coordination for Java volatile fields' reads & writes across threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, java-memory-model

I have the following code:

```
 private volatile boolean run = true;

 private Object lock =new Object();
```

.........

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " run:" + run);

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " setting run to false");

                run = false;

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " run:" + run);
            }
        }});

newThread.start();

while(true) {//no synchronization, so no coordination guarantee
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "* run: "+run);

    if(run == false) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "** run: "+run+"\nExiting...");
    System.exit(0);
    }
}




which generates the following output:



main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
Thread-0 setting run to false
Thread-0 run:false
main* run: true    <- what causes this???
main** run: false
Exiting...
```

I'm trying to understand why in the main thread the aberration of **main* run: true** is occurring considering `run` is a volatile field and according to Java Memory Model spec, the volatile write in `Thread-0` should be visible by the `main`thread instantaneously.  I'm aware that synchronization in the `Thread-0` is extraneous here, but am confused about this behavior of a volatile.  What am I missing here?

Another, even weirder run produced this:

```
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main** run: false
Exiting...
Thread-0 run:false
```

Or is this behavior to be expected and if so, why? Thanks.

**Edit:** As asked in the comments, I'm updating the post with the expected output which I'm seeing sometimes but not all of the time:

```
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
Thread-0 setting run to false
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
Thread-0 run:false
main** run: false
Exiting...
```

In other words, I don't want to see:

```
main* run: true
```

to appear after

```
Thread-0 run:false
```

or

```
main** run: false
Exiting...
```

to appear before

```
Thread-0 run:false
```

Comment: Please make a mvce. People who want to run your posted code shouldnt have to reconstruct it from incomplete snippets.

Comment: @NathanHughes: what's a mvce?

Comment: There's another shared resource in this scenario : `System.out`.

Comment: mvce = minimum valuable code example.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: would you mind explaining?

Comment: You seem to assume that because a line appears on stdout that that line was written first.  That assumes things about PrintStream's concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just look at the reads and writes of the volatile variable, then they have to appear in the order:

```
1 - main: read run (run is true)
2 - Thread-0: write run (run is false)
3 - main: read run (run is false)
```

But the console outputs are separate actions that don't need to occur immediately after the read. The evaluation of the parameters to println and calling the method is not atomic. So we have something more like:

```
1 - main: read run (run is true)
2 - main: println("Run: true")

3 - Thread-0: write run (run is false)
4 - Thread-0: println("Run: false")

5 - main: read run (run is false)
6 - main: println("Run: false")
```

This allows an ordering which follows the first ordering like:

```
1 - main: read run (run is true)

3 - Thread-0: write run (run is false)
4 - Thread-0: println("Run: false")

2 - main: println("Run: true")

5 - main: read run (run is false)
6 - main: println("Run: false")
```

Based on the source code in [PrintWriter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.println%28java.lang.String%29), the line:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " run:" + run);
```

could be inlined something like:

```
String x = Thread.currentThread().getName() + " run:" + run;
synchronized(System.out.lock) {
    System.out.print(x);
    System.out.println();
}
```

so there is synchronization within `println` but it doesn't include the read of `run`. This means that the value of `run` can change between it being read and it being output, resulting in the old value of `run` being output.

To get the output you're expecting, then the synchronized block would need to include the setting of `run` and the `println` statements together. And the reading of `run` and the `println` statements on the other thread would need to be in another synchronized block on the same lock.

Comment: Could you expand on:"The evaluation of the parameters to println and calling the method is not atomic."  The `println` is present in both treads, which would cause its internal synchronization ( however it does it, I don't have the source) across the both threads on the same monitor object, I assume.  Or would it be the wrong assumption?  So why explicit synchronization seem to work fine (for as many trials I did) but volatile produces this weird aberrations sometimes?  Is it correct as per JMM that `volatile` and `synchronized` exhibit those implicit differences?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon The different is the number of statements included within the synchronization block. The explicit synchronization includes the reading and writing of `run`, but the implicit synchronization doesn't, allowing it to print an old value after it changes. I've added the source code for PrintWriter.

Comment: Yes, that explanation (similar to what Rafael is saying albeit in different words, looks like) makes logical sense from reconstructing the sequence of events.  To what you are saying, looks like this coarse synchronization is happening inside `PrintStream` (which System.out is set to via JNI) inside whose `println(String)` the whole printing is synchronized on `this`.  I'm assuming that this PrintStream and the fact that it's injected via native code would make it a singleton across different threads (main & Thread-0 in my case) but perhaps that assumption is wrong which could also explain...

Comment: ...the mismatch, given that the printing is synchronized on different monitors?  Wonder why they chose to implement `PrintStream`'s println in that manner without documenting its synchronization behavior explicitly, it certainly makes one guess given that this code is really extremely simple.  Why not have the println() accept, along with a String, an external lock object, this way  we could explicitly guard our code across the whole boundary of setting the text and flushing it?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Yes, the instances of PrintStream are the same across different threads. I think the intent of PrintStream's synchronization is just to prevent half of one line appearing in the middle of another. So one line has to finish printing before the next one starts. If you need extra synchronization, you can always add it yourself. Usually, only internal locks are used to retain control over what else can synchronize on them, preventing deadlocks, or unnecessary blocking.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the problem. The lock here is useless. Also volatile means that the variable is synchronized within itself. Here what happen. Whenever there are multiple threads, each one runs by itself without caring for the other ones. So in this case we have two threads: main and thread-0. Main runs by itself and reaches a point where it prints the variable `run` so it prints it. The other thread sleeps a little (which should not matter and should not be a way let other thread to do work first) and then changes the variable `run` to false. Main thread reads the new value and exists

Follow the time sequence and you will understand

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " run:" + run);

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " setting run to false");

            run = false; //<---- time_4

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " run:" + run); //<---- time_5
        }
    }});

newThread.start();

while(true) { //<---- time_2
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "* run: "+run); //<--- time_3 getting the value of run variable. //<---- time_6 printing

    if(run == false) { //<---- time_1 (run == true) // <---- 2nd iteration time_7 (run == false)
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "** run: "+run+"\nExiting..."); //<---- time_8
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Anyways, here is how to fix your code to get the expected output (note: volatile did not do anything in here):

```
synchronized (lock) {
                if(run == false) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "** run: "+run+"\nExiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
```

This is what volatile does basically for variable `run`:

```
// run = false; //becomes ========
synchronized(someLock) {
    run = flase;
}
// =======================


//System.out.println(run); //becomes =========   
synchronized(someLock) {
    boolean tmpBoolean = run;
}
System.out.println(tmpBoolean);
//=================
```

Comment: Well, I'm expecting the correct behavior to be something like`main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
Thread-0 setting run to false
main* run: true
main* run: true
main* run: true
Thread-0 run:false
main** run: false
Exiting...
` which sometimes happens.  So why are the above aberrations?

Comment: can you edit the post with the expected behavior. It is hard to read in a comment thank you

Comment: Yes, I understand that the flow you describe.  What confuses me, though, is the fact that that even though `run` designated as volatile, the `main` thread doesn't gets its updated values upon its update in `Tread-0` (see first snippet) and in the second, the flow of things (as per System.out.println) seems to be totally out of order: the `main` exits even before the `run` is updated in the `Thread-0`

Comment: I added the expected behavior in the text of the post.  Thanks

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The time stamps you put in seem to be re-odering the `program order` in the `main` thread - wouldn't it violate the contract for the `run` defined as `volatile` as per Java Memory Model spec?

Comment: what JMM spec you talking about

Comment: JMM == Java Memory Model: A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

Comment: I understand, where is the thing you read. Where is the spec? Can you share

Comment: Also §17.4.4 there: A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.  So I'm trying to understand why that `happens-before` order doesn't get respected by the output I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your fix, and it would work of course, but I specifically mentioned that synchronization is outside the scope of the question.  My question was that `volatile` semantic should provide similar `happen-before` guarantees as synchronization (at least per my understanding of the spec), but what I am observing contradicts that.  I wanted to understand why and if fixing the snippet is required, how would one fix it using 'volatile' in the main thread (instead of relying on synchronize block.

Answer (score 1):

As for the correctness of your program, the `synchronized` block is entirely unneccessary. If you only ever synchronize a lock from a single thread, there is a good chance that the [JIT compiler eliminates this lock altogether](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/biased_locking_in_hotspot).

What is properly confusing you is the JMM guarantee that a `volatile` field is guaranteed to be seen with its updated value by other threads after it was written. This guarantee does however **not** imply that the thread writing the `volatile` field communicates this value immediately and stalls until the new value was communicated to all other threads. Instead, the guarantee is that other thread eventually need to see the updated value.

This means that if thread A writes to a `volatile` field, thread B is guaranteed to:

1. Eventually see this new value.
2. Not read any values written previously to the volatile field with their "old" value.

Also, note that calling `System.out.println` implicitly synchronizes on the `System.out` object (look at the `PrintWriter` code). Considering the fact that you synchronize both of your threads on a single monitor also explains the observed output. I assume that the string is created while the `System.out` monitor is locked by your field-setting thread. In this case, the thread first creates the string to write and then waits for the other thread to release this monitor which is why the output with the "old" content is something you commonly observe.

What I mean by that is that the statement

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "* run: " + run);
```

is not atomic. Broken up in two steps, the statement is equivalent to:

```
String text = Thread.currentThread().getName() + "* run: " + run;
System.out.println(text);
```

Given this non-atomicity, the chain of events (naming your threads *A* and *B*) is like:

```
/*A*/ String text = Thread.currentThread().getName() + "* run: " + run;
/*B*/ System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " setting run to false");
/*B*/ run = false;
/*B*/ System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " run:" + run);
/*A*/ System.out.println(text);
/*A*/ if(run == false) {
/*A*/ System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "** run: " + run + "\nExiting...");
/*A*/ System.exit(0);
/*A*/ }
```

This outcome is probably also the most common one due to a [lock coarsening](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rinard/paper/jpdc98.pdf) optimization where each loop is holding the entirety of any of your loop's bodys. The only thing that is done outside of this coarsed lock is the creation of the first string value which is the old value that you observe.

For more information on the JMM, I [once summarized my understanding in a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgiXKPEILoc). Also, have a look at [cache coherence protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence#Coherency_protocols) which eventually decide upon visibility.

Comment: Rafael, I listened to your talk yesterday, and that's what, partially, inspired me to dig deeper into understanding this output's behavior.  I still am confused.  You say: "When A wants to print to the console, it needs to reaquire the monitor for System.out which causes the buffer to be flushed such that the subsequent message in B prints the updated message."  However this sequence contradicts that premise: `Thread-0 run:false`
`main* run: true`
`main** run: false`.   As you see, `main` still prints `true` even after it's supposedly been flushed by `Thrd-0` upon printing. Is print atomic?

Comment: Or would it be that the `main* run: true` is a vestige from a non-flushed print buffer on the `main` thread?  But you are saying: "This means that if thread A writes to a volatile field, thread B is guaranteed to: 2. Not read any values previously written with their previous value." which I didn't quite grasped.  If you could possibly expand on it...  Seems `volatile` is not quite as strict in terms of inter-thread coordination as `synchronized` would be, even though the JMM doesn't seem to explicitly distinquish them, would it be fair to say?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused which output you expected and which you did not expect. I updated my answer, the other output is just as logical.

Comment: Yes Rafael, as I put in the comment to @fgb just now, you both seem to be saying similar things.  They sound sensible.  Would appreciate you opinions on my queries in that comment as well.  Thanks.